# Selecting elements by attributes of given value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the table below.  I also have this array who's values correspond to the data-id attributes of the rows **[52,24,12]**.  One and only one row will exist in the table for each array value.  I would like to increment the count column for each row which exists in the array.  For instance, 12 would change to 13, 32 would change to 33, and 6 would change to 7.  A jQuery solution is preferred, however, a native JavaScript solution would suffice.  Thank you

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr><td>count</td></tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr data-id="24"><td>32</td></tr>
  <tr data-id="52"><td>12</td></tr>
  <tr data-id="42"><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr data-id="84"><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr data-id="12"><td>6</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you post the code you are using to actually create the array?

Comment: var myArray=$('#list input:checked');

Comment: Everyone of these answers is awesome!  trolee's second answer is seems the simplest, however, don't know if it the most efficient.  Regardless, I have to pick something, so...  Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I'm using lib from underscorejs.org)

```
_.each([52,24,12], function (item) {
    var td = $('tr[data-id=' + item + '] td');
    td.text(parseInt(td.text()) + 1);
});
```

or w/o underscore:

```
var a = [52,24,12]; 
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    var td = $('tr[data-id=' + a[i] + '] td');
    td.text(parseInt(td.text()) + 1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ACJ9r/

Answer (score 1):

[Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/GgqLe/1/) should do the trick

```
var indices = [52, 24, 12];

//loop through each array entry
jQuery.each(indices, function(i, val) {

    var tr, value;

    //get the tr with the corresponding data-id, cache for reuse
    td = $('tr[data-id="' + val + '"] td');

    //just trying to be verbose
    value = td.text();           //get the text
    value = parseInt(value, 10); //parse the number off it
    value++;                     //increment

    //put the incremented values back
    td.text(value);

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**HTML**:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr><td>count</td></tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr data-id="24"><td>32</td></tr>
  <tr data-id="52"><td>12</td></tr>
  <tr data-id="42"><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr data-id="84"><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr data-id="12"><td>6</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>​
```

**jQuery**:

```
indices = [52, 24, 12];

$('tr[data-id]').each(function() {
    if (indices.indexOf($(this).data('id')) == -1) {
        return;
    }
    var td = parseInt($(this).find('td').html());  
    $(this).find('td').html(td + 1);
});
```

**JsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Xc7JC/1/

Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: This doesn't operate only on the numbers in the array of IDs.  This operates on all rows that have an id.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this to operate only on the rows who's ID exists in your array.

This is likely more efficient than solutions that use multiple jQuery calls to look up each id in the array because this just goes through the rows once whereas those have to go through the table rows N times.

```
<table id="myTable">
 <thead>
  <tr><td>count</td></tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr data-id="24"><td>32</td></tr>
  <tr data-id="52"><td>12</td></tr>
  <tr data-id="42"><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr data-id="84"><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr data-id="12"><td>6</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

var rowList = [52, 24, 12];

$("#myTable tr").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    if (id && $.inArray(id, rowList) != -1) {
        var cell = $(this).find("td");
        cell.text(parseInt(cell.text(), 10) + 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: @user1032531 - fixed a couple typos and updated my answer.  Works now: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/t2YyP/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/EMTpQ/1/)**

```
arr = [52,24,12];
$('tr').each(function(){
    if($.inArray($(this).data('id'), arr) > -1)
        $(this).children('td').text(+$(this).children('td').text()+1);
});​
```